# Cannot arrange between Text and LinearProgressIndicator in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, linearprogressindicator

I'm trying to put the Text that represents the percentage higher than the LinearProgressIndicator bar, I've tried many ways but none of them work.
You can see it in the photo below:

[image]

And here is my code, you can see that I tried to raise it higher but it didn't work, Maybe I need to redesign it. If you are an expert in designing with Jetpack compose, please let me know, thank you very much:

```html
@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun CoursesItem(
    courses: Courses,
    process: Processes,
    onCourseItemClick: (String) -> Unit,
    id : String,
    viewModel: CoursesViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .cardCourses()
            .clickable { viewModel.onCourseItemClick(onCourseItemClick, id) },
        elevation = 4.dp
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .align(Alignment.TopStart) // Đặt cách trên cùng
            ) {
                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    AsyncImage(
                        model = courses.image,
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .AsyncImageCardCourses()
                            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary)
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = courses.nameCourses,
                            color = Color.DarkGray,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
                        Text(
                            text = courses.description,
                            color = Color.Gray,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
                        )
                        // this is part to fix
                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                                .padding(top = 10.dp),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                        ) {
                            LinearProgressIndicator(
                                progress = (process.processesLearn.toFloat()),
                                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                            )
                            Text(
                                text = "${(process.processesLearn * 100).toInt()}%",
                                color = Color.Black,
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption,
                                modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline()
                            )
                        }

                    }
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = { viewModel.onCourseItemClick(onCourseItemClick, id) },
                        modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowForward,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            tint = Color.Gray
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .align(Alignment.BottomCenter) // Đặt ở dưới cùng
            ) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `.padding(top = 10.dp)`, try adding `Spacer(Modifier.height(10.dp)` above `Row()`. Text seems to be cut because of padding

Comment: oh i tried your way but it didn't work, this is picture after i try:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/learningenglishapp-1e3bd.appspot.com/o/L%E1%BB%97i.png?alt=media&token=7ea8d3bc-304f-47ff-bc3d-e467a0577fe5

Comment: Please share what are AsyncImageCardCourses() and cardCourses()
If you hardcode the height of the cell - It might be the problem

Comment: Yes, of course:
this is Async
`fun Modifier.AsyncImageCardCourses(): Modifier {
  return this.size(50.dp)
    .clip(CircleShape)
}`

And here is cardCourses():
`fun Modifier.cardCourses(): Modifier {
  return this.padding(8.dp)
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .height(120.dp)
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
fun Modifier.cardCourses(): Modifier {
    return this.padding(8.dp).fillMaxWidth().height(120.dp) //<--try higher number
}
```

Then for this code:

```
// this is part to fix
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        .padding(top = 10.dp), //<-- try lower number
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    LinearProgressIndicator(
        progress = (process.processesLearn.toFloat()),
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    )
...
)
```

Comment: Yes, but my problem is the text cannot higher, i want it move higher

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer you should let some more space from  `cardCourses()` `modifier` and then move the row up from `row Modifier` in order to move the text up...

Comment: Yes, thank you, it worked after i fix height is 125.dp